# How to automatically switch to terminal when it finished its command's execution?

Tags: bash, shell-script, window-manager

Let's say I run a timeintensive command

```
sh do_the_timeintensive_thing.sh
```

and switch to another window (eg. webbrowser, IDE, etc.). Now what I would like to have is that after do_the_timeintensive_thing.sh finished, the terminal executing the script automatically pops up/is switched to. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: No idea how to do this, but you can make it "ring" by echoing the bell character afterwards.

Comment: That depends on the windowmanager or desktop environment you are using.  Which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this, with `xdotool`:

```
thisWindow=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
sh do_the_timeintensive_thing.sh ; xdotool windowactivate "$thisWindow"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can regain focus with a tool like `xdotool` or `wmctrl`.

```
# get the window id
sh do_the_timeintensive_thing.sh
# transfer the focus to the window id
```

Alternatively, something like:

```
sh do_the_timeintensive_thing.sh;xeyes
```

Will graphically let you know when it's done.